# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'xxx' of 'useAuth(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

Working with React Context and Hooks I am creating a provider called AuthProvider and from the useAuth Hook I call that context to work with it. I have a component called Login in which I call my Hook to access the AuthProvider as follows:

```
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth'

const Login = () => {

  const { hello } = useAuth() 

  console.log(hello);

...
```

In AuthContext I have the variable "hello" that I pass to the children of my context.

AuthProvider:

```
const AuthContext = createContext()

const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {

    const hello= 'hello'

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ hello }}>
          {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      )
}

export {
     AuthProvider
}

export default AuthContext
```

UseAuth Hook:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthProvider";

const useAuth  = () => {

     return useContext(AuthContext)

}

export default useAuth
```

[image: Context Routes]

And this is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hello')
```

Comment: But I'm passing it from my context to the login component through the hook

Comment: An apology, my mistake when translating, I already corrected it and "hello" is the well-written variable. The error persists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the component you use context but was not wrapped under a context provider

To fix, wrap the component or the root component that has the component as a children under a context provider

```
<AuthProvider>
  <Login />
</AuthProvider>
```

#### Demo

[image: Edit pedantic-stonebraker-myzk4e]

#### References

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: Thanks friend, I already made that point by enclosing the routes where I need to use the context, I have updated in my question.

Comment: @OscarDev what react-router version you are using?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2"

Comment: @OscarDev just updated the sandbox example like yours recent edit and it still works

Comment: Thank you! Now if it works, I am left wondering why now it works?